# SQL: trying to get the number of transactions when it's the first transaction by a user (new revenue)

Tags: sql

I have a table called `subscription_transaction` that has a `subscription_id`, `user_id`, and `timestamp`.

These are payment transactions, and I want to figure out my "new revenue" daily. That would be the number of transactions by a user who is making their first transaction.

I have tried the following but I get no results.

```
SELECT Floor(Extract(epoch FROM t1.timestamp) / 86400) * 86400 AS "time", 
       Count(t1.id) * 60 
FROM   subscription_transaction t1 
WHERE  t1.event = 'one-time payment' 
       AND t1.subscription_id = 28 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   subscription_transaction t2 
                   WHERE  t2.user_id = t1.user_id 
                          AND t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp 
                   LIMIT  1) 
GROUP  BY 1 
ORDER  BY 1
```

And if I flip the `<` sign in the nested `SELECT`, making it `t2.timestamp > t1.timestamp`, I get *all* transactions.

Can anybody help?
Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific features used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT Floor(Extract(epoch FROM t1.timestamp) / 86400) * 86400 AS "time", 
       Count(t1.id) * 60 
FROM   subscription_transaction t1 
WHERE  t1.event = 'one-time payment' 
       AND t1.subscription_id = 28 
       -- AND t1.timestamp = today -- 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   subscription_transaction t2 
                   WHERE  t2.user_id = t1.user_id 
                     AND  t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp ) 
-- if there is possibility of having same customer doing 2 transaction today 
-- and you want the data of both the transaction then you compare   
-- t2.timestamp <= t1.timestamp - 1 day   
GROUP  BY 1 
ORDER  BY 1
```

You would also want to add condition on `t1.timestamp` to fetch today's transaction only